# Issues with Reputation on Documentation

Tags: support, documentation

One concern with the current reputation distribution system is the fairness of distributing reputation to all users with "substantive" edits (how is "substantive" itself even defined??). This makes it very easy to "piggy back" on the work of others for reputation gains. While to an extent, it is a collaborative process, I feel like the reputation gain should be scaled to the size of a user's contribution, rather than being an even distribution of +10 per upvote. Any user could make an early "substantive" change with only a few small edits (but sufficient to trip the barrier), but another user who later makes a huge change, contributing a much larger amount of information, will gain the exact same amount of reputation for subsequent upvotes as the previous user. Thus, by sheer luck, users can unduly gain reputation through others' work.

Comment: This will probably become less of an issue as documentation becomes refined enough that small edits become harder to get accepted.